# How to find length of parameter input of function?

Tags: python, function, scipy, one-definition-rule, argument-unpacking

I'm trying to use Scipy's `ODR` to fit various different curves to data. These curves have to be given as an ODR Model, which is defined by a function. This function has two arguments: `p` and `x`. `p` is a list of the parameters that will be optimised. Example:

```
def f(p, x):
  m, c = p
  return m*x + c

model = Model(f)
data = RealData(xdata, ydata)
odr_setup = ODR(data, model, beta0=[0,0], partol=0.001)
odr_result = odr_setup.run()
```

**My problem:** the length of `p` depends on the function I am fitting. If the length of `beta0` and `p` are not the same, it gives a `ValueError`. To get round this, I have constructed some nested `try-except` statements to get the matching length. Is there a more elegant way of achieving the same thing?

Ideally I would like something like `ODR(data, model, ***beta0=[0]*n_params***, partol=0.001)`. How would I find `n_params`? Or is there a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more clear on how n_params depends on p? It isn't just ```len(p)``` if that is the case ```beta=[0] * len(p)```

Comment: Basically I am looking for len(p), yes. The problem is that I don't know how to access p from just having the function. There are different functions with different lengths of p being passed around. As far as I know, the only way to tell the length of p would be to go inside the function and see p get unpacked... how?